# Check if there is any common element in both lists : Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I was working on this simple program to check if there are common elements in two lists
so the code I have written uses nested if but was wondering is there any better way to do this instead of using the nested format.

```
def common_data(list1, list2):
     result = False
     for x in list1:
         for y in list2:
             if x == y:
                 result = True
                 return result
```

Also is there a way to check for the common elements in n number of lists?

Comment: So if there is no common element, you want to return `None`? Then what is that `False` for?

Comment: didn't use it here but as in an answer to string like `print("there is a common element: ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` to iterate over one list and check containment in the other. This has the benefit of short circuiting upon finding the first contained element.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> any(i in b for i in a)
True
```

Alternatively you can check the size of a `set.intersection` between the two lists

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> len(set(a).intersection(b)) > 0
True
```

Comment: ... assuming said elements are hashable

Comment: @DeepSpace for the `set` alternative yes, for the `any` solution there is no hash requirement

Comment: of course, I wrote the comment when there was only the `set` solution :)

Comment: How about `bool` instead of `len`?

Answer (score 1):

The first option is the easiest. You want to know if there are any elements from list 1 that are in list 2. Generator comprehensions can almost directly turn that english idea into code. It's inefficient for large lists, but it's super easy to code.

```
result = any(x in list2 for x in list1)
```

If your elements are hashable you can improve on that by using sets for an O(1) containment lookup. Note that we only want to create a set out of the smallest list to minimize the extra memory and work for that operation, and we use the `any()` builtin to allow this to short-circuit and exit early if we immediately find an item in list2.

```
if len(list1) > len(list2):
    list1, list2 = list2, list1
cache = set(list1)
result = any(x in cache for x in list2)
```

Another option in case your elements aren't hashable and are sortable is to sort both lists, merge them, and check for duplicates (it's critical that this is a full order that matches your definition of equality -- when elements are different one should be less than the other).

It's worth noting that this has a fairly high object creation overhead because of all the additional tuples. It might be worth writing your own routine to step through the two sorted lists and keep track of which one the previous element came from rather than calling into `heapq.merge()`.

```
import heapq

list1, list2, prev, result = sorted(list1), sorted(list2), None, False
for item, i in heapq.merge(
        ((x, 1) for x in list1),
        ((x, 2) for x in list2)):
    if prev and item==prev[0] and i!=prev[1]:
        result = True
        break
    prev = (item, i)
```

It's probably also worth noting that if the only operation you have available is equality testing (objects aren't sortable, hashable, etc) you can't improve the worst-case in general beyond O(nm) for len(list1)==n and len(list2)==m. There are interesting special case still (e.g. if the number of unique elements is small), but if you don't have some additional information about the problem you can't do better than the naive solution.

Comment: so, two things are we importing heapq to implement the priority queue algorithm? and secondly, if I'm not wrong wouldn't using .sort() with lists be faster? like why create a copy?

Comment: (1) We're importing heapq purely for their `merge()` routine, which does use a priority queue behind the scenes, but I didn't want to add a couple lines of code to an already mildly verbose answer. (2) Using `.sort()` should be faster. I created copies because your question didn't indicate that mutating a list was allowed (e.g. if somebody else has a reference to them and needs them to have a different order), so my answer was a bit defensive.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are hashable...

Shorter expression:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 =    [2, 3, 4]
>>> bool(set(list1) & set(list2))
True
```

For your "n number of lists" question:

```
>>> lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                      [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> bool(set(lists[0]).intersection(*lists))
True
```

And of course you might not need the explicit conversion to `bool` if you're just going to use it in boolean contexts like `if ... :` or if you do want to know the common elements:

```
>>> if set(list1) & set(list2):
        print('common!')

common!

>>> set(list1) & set(list2)
{2, 3}

>>> set(lists[0]).intersection(*lists)
{4, 5}
```